# Need to configure Springboot and react app in circle ci

Tags: reactjs, maven, spring-boot, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I am trying to configure my project in circle ci, having spring boot as backend and react as a frontend.

I am bundling my frontend directory with the backend and running the npm commands with maven clean install.

But when I am building the same in circle ci, it is giving me error stating **not able to find npm inside cicleci/project/frontend**

Can anyone help me on this?